# How to name assets for different screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, assets, screen-resolution, windows-8.1

My app has over 100 images. And how to I specify resources for other resolutions? I see both methods.

One by naming the folders `scale-100` and other by naming each file with a suffix of scale 100. My app is developed in C#. And how do I test which image is taken?

For now my folder structure is

```
Assets -> Images-> scale-100 -> tab_icon_notes_clicked_1366.png
```

And in the code when I need to reference the image, I reference it like this.

```
("ms-appx:/Assets/Images/tab_icon_notes_clicked_1366.png");
```

So without using `scale-100` in the image path, it is retrieving an image. I have another folder named as `scale-140` in which the higher resolution of the same image is placed. But I cant figure out which image it is taking.. `scale-100` or `scale-140` ?

Comment: Create some assets that have the text `scale-100` or `scale-140` stamped across the image. Then place those images on screen, and you should quickly be able to work out which version is being used.

Comment: also you can find the Display Scale info using  DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale property & the system will take the images automatically for the respective scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the System Display Scale Information by the Code below

```
var scaleInfo= DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale;
```

The system will take care of loading the correct Scale Images from the respective Scale Folders [100,140,180].